# Using interface references to Collections

Tags: java, design-patterns, collections, interface

We use interface references to Collections. Is it only for the good coding practice or have some logic behind it? Can anyone explain?

For example:

We use

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Instead of

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having `interface` will allow you to change the implementation in future transparently (Without many changes on client side).

For example:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Even though you change implementation to LinkedHashMap, client don't need to make any changes on their end.

If you use

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Client is tightly coupled with implementation. If you change implementation, then you need to change client also.

One draw back would be, If you would like to use any implementation specific methods, you need to cast to the corresponding type and use it.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `HashMap` your implementation becomes specific to `HashMap` but if you use `Map` you can change it to any `Map Implementation` in future.

You can read **Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces** From Effective Java.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you code to the contract of a component, not to the implementation.  There are many implementations of java.util.Map, and can be interchanged seamlessly should the need arise, provided your code depends solely on the interface.

Loose coupling in general is good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Code Maintenance is one advantage, if someone wants to use some other concrete `Map`, you need to change only one line versus dozens. It may not seem like that in your code snippet example, it's only when the use of object references become prevalent in parameters and return types that the problems arise. I suppose it is just better to start "thinking in interfaces" rather than objects from the beginning to avoid the tendency to write code that brings these problems about. 
Quoting [Allen Hollub](http://www.holub.com/) here

> If you write your client code such that it is only concerned with the capabilities guaranteed by an interface rather than the actual implementation by a particular class, you will have more freedom to change implementations in the future.

Answer (score 1):

With something as follows -

```
class MapTest {
    Map<String, Integer> map;

    public MapTest(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    //do stuffs with map
}
```

you can pass in different implementations of `Map`. But if `map` was of type `HashMap` then it would alwasy have to be a `HashMap` (or it's subclass if you subclass it).

Answer (score 0):

First approach is ***much more flexible*** then second:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

This way, you have to change only one line if you decide to use a `TreeMap` instead.

Also, methods that operate on sets should specify parameters of type `Map`:

```
public static void print(Map<String, Integer> s)
```

Then the method can be used for all map implementations.

In theory, we should make the same recommendation for linked lists, namely to save `LinkedList` references in variables of type `List`.